# getting object with slug or pk in querysets

Tags: regex, django, django-views

In django doc says that

```
>>> entry = Entry.objects.get(id=10)
```

is faster than this:

```
>>> entry = Entry.object.get(headline="News Item Title")
```

So I changed my view from this:

```
def myview(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    #...
```

to this:

```
def myview(request, id, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    #...
```

But my slug is not used in my view. In that case both urls below get the correct post because of valid regex:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/posts/5/my-first-post/
127.0.0.1:8000/posts/5/mylblablabalg/
```

And I dont want this. Then I canged my view to this:

```
def myview(request, id, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if post.slug == slug:
        return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'post': post})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:index', args=(id, post.slug)))
```

It does what I want which redirects the same page with the corrected slug but I doubt if it is ok in terms of performanse. What about **db_index**? Should I use it in **SlugField**?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to pull posts from the database via the SlugField, then yes, you should tell the database to index that field for performance increase. You should also set it to unique.

Comment: If I do what you said then my posts will be get to me with index searching right?

Comment: yes, database performance will be much faster as index searches are way faster than the database having to search through a varchar list.